# How do you handle "impossible" exceptions in Java?

Tags: java, exception

Sometimes, I'll end up having to catch an exception that I know can never happen, such as here

```
URLDecoder.decode("some string", "UTF-8"); //No unknown encoding possible
```

or here:

```
public void methodWithURL(URL url){
    URI uri = new URI(url); //No invalud URI syntax possible
}
```

How do you handle this? I generally log a funny error regarding how the laws of the universe have changed, and then throw a `RuntimeException`. Is there a better way?

Comment: try/catch(XXXException _ex){throw new AssertionError(_ex);}

Comment: @bestsss I've also heard of AssertionError as alternative to RuntimeException. Is that the general way to do this over RuntimeException, or just a better way of subclassing this type of errors? thx! (also, you might want to write in the answers section)

Comment: Error does not extend Exception, so it bypasses the overused `try/catch(Exception any)`. Anything that catches `Throwable` shall deal w/ `Error` explicitly. Client code shall not catch `Error` for no reason either. Solely logging exception that *shall not happen* is usually not the right thing to do. And, no I do not want to try an answer :)

Comment: I for one quite like funny messages, so I'd leave it in. Expect a joyless muppet to change it in future, but your legacy will always be in the SVN history ;].

Comment: @bestsss thanks a lot, `AssertionError` seems like a good idea, and I like the "invulnerability" it gets from generic catches on Exception thanks to it being an Error.

Comment: @davidfrancis Sounds good :) I'd hope that good code, correctly documented, *and* with a bit of humor shouldn't anger anyone...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I catch the `Exception` and wrap it in an `Error`. from the doc of `Error` :

> An Error is a subclass of Throwable that indicates serious problems
>   that a reasonable application should not try to catch.

Comment: Thanks a lot Julien. I am now rather convinced that throwing an `Error` derivate is the best way. @bestsss also made some suggestions in the question's comment section, including the use of AssertionError

Comment: +1 Now _this_ is a really solid answer.  It is not specific like `AssertionError` (which might look odd in the absence of an `assert` statement) and has the same effect as `RuntimeException`.  Plus it indicates a trouble with the "system" rather than the logic of the code.  Like.  I wonder if this approach is widely known or not, or if there are any downsides?

Comment: *Plus it indicates a trouble with the "system"* That's `InternalError` for.  I used to use it in 1.1 but switched to `AssetionError` in 1.4 (offers a c-tor w/ Throwable too). Also some errors may not be exactly result of system error but programming ones or dataraces. Btw, few places in java use `System.exit(-1)`

Answer (score 6):

I would skip the funny message.

BTW: I had a case where a piece of code (in a small library) just assumed that an encoding would be available. Only it got deployed on a limited device and exploded at runtime.

Checked exceptions serve to show places in our code where we should pause for a second and consider the paths less traveled (as in "what my app does when network dies" and other corner cases). Wrapping them in IllegalStateException and rethrowing is a sort of a signed contract, where the programmer says: "yes, all risks considered I take full responsibility for the spot right here". If it wasn't for checked exceptions, we would hava no way of knowing a consious decision from a plain lack of thought.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your example on making the impossible possible. This is exactly what I was afraid of, and that's why I wanted to check with you guys. Also, I wasn't ranting against checked exceptions, I consider them a fundamental part of Java, but was wondering on how to handle the impossible (really unlikely?) ones

Comment: Seems nice, because running the code on JRE than has no UTF-8 encoding is an illegal state.

Answer (score 3):

Well, IMHO there *is* a better way than "log[ging] a funny error regarding how the laws of the universe have changed" because in doing so you are "being cute," which among friends is fine but is not universally (no pun intended) accepted.  Your code may be read by others and if your humor falls flat (on them) you haven't really made any friends.

Many style guides make suggestions for impossible exceptions.  You can use an empty catch block with the exception parameter being named `willNeverHappen`; you can place a comment in the empty block; you can throw a runtime exception (probably the best, since you **MIGHT** misspell UTF-8!)

If you want to be super ambitious, you can write an annotation, like [SneakyThrows in Lombok](http://projectlombok.org/features/SneakyThrows.html).  Whether you would consider this "better" is simply a matter of taste. :)

Note that this question was discussed on https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/122233/how-to-deal-with-checked-exceptions-that-cannot-ever-be-thrown.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Ray; I'm not sure I'd recommend empty catch blocks (comment or not), but you have a point that impossible options *might* become possible one day. As to the humor, I'm sure there's many opinions (perhaps depends on company culture?) but you are right that no one should suffer a bug for hours, only to find it caused by a mishandled exception and a funny message.

Comment: I hate the empty catch block too: "eating" exceptions is horrible practice.  And yes I did try to say that humor was okay in some circles; it just carries a risk that it might not be understood by a future reader of the code, so such an approach should be carefully considered.  If chosen, it is best to make it something _all_ readers will understand and not something that relies on a pop culture or a reference to something esoteric.  A "violation of the laws of the universe" is _probably_ okay.  That said, `RuntimeException` or its cousin `Error` are the best bet.

Answer (score 1):

If you use [Lombok](https://projectlombok.org/) in your project, you can annotate the surrounding method with [`@SneakyThrows`](https://projectlombok.org/features/SneakyThrows) which kind of hides checked exceptions <s>in `RuntimeException`</s> (thus no need to surround by `try-catch` nor declare it in `throws` clause).

For instance:

```java
@SneakyThrows(URISyntaxException.class)
public void methodWithURL(URL url) { // No throws here
    URI uri = new URI(url); // Assume no invalud URI syntax possible
}
```

**EDIT:** Actually, `@SneakyThrows` is **not** converting checked exceptions into `RuntimeException`, it rather prevents the compiler from seeing the checked exception is declared or thrown, so beware that in the (maybe unlikely) event that this hidden exception is thrown, a `catch(RuntimeException)` statement around that method won't catch it.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my solution -- developed for Android but can be easily adapted for "regular" Java:

```
public class ImpossibleException extends RuntimeException {
    public ImpossibleException(@NonNull String whyNotPossible) {
        this(whyNotPossible, null);
    }

    public ImpossibleException(@NonNull String whyNotPossible, Throwable throwable) {
        super("Impossible exception: " + whyNotPossible, throwable);
        Log.e("Impossible", whyNotPossible, throwable);
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
try {
    byte[] data = "Hello".getBytes("utf-8");
    Log.i("Test", "data.length=" + data.length);
} catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
    throw new ImpossibleException("Android always supports utf-8", e);
}
```

The `whyNotPossible` constructor means there's no need to log the error where it happens, and there's also no need for a comment.

I guess it's a matter of taste if this should be an `ImpossibleException extends RuntimeException` or an `ImpossibleError extends Error`.